# how to get id of next element jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here the html code, and i want to get the id of next element from clicked element a with class coba or to get id of  element table class coba2.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <label>Kategori</label>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="jenis_kues" data-toggle="dropdown">Tambah Pertanyaan
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="jenis_kues">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a class="coba" id="teks" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="tambah_kues_teks()">Teks</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<table class="coba2" id="kues_teks-'+i+'">
</table></div>
```

and i've tried using this script

```
var a = $('.coba').next('.coba2'); alert(a.attr('id'));
```

but it show me undefined, anyone know how?

Comment: Where is the second element with classname = "coba"?

Comment: There seems to be spurious `</div>` at the end of your code. Could you please verify if the code you posted is correct?

Comment: *" i want to get the id of next element from clicked element a with class coba"*- it's the only child, there is no `next` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to travel up the DOM tree, until you are on the same level as `.coba2`:

```
var id = $('.coba').closest('.dropdown').next('.coba2').attr('id');
alert( id );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
var a = $('.coba').parents('.dropdown').next('.coba2'); alert(a.attr('id'));
```